# How to return a single object from an array in Javascript to another variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
contacts: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "John Doe",
      email: "john@gmail.com",
      phone: "555-555-5555",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Karen Williams",
      email: "karen@gmail.com",
      phone: "444-444-4444",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Henry Johnson",
      email: "henry@gmail.com",
      phone: "333-333-333",
    },
  ]
```

I want to loop through them and if one of their ID's matches the ID I am looking for then I need that return and assigned to another variable.
This is what I have so far but it tells me the `selectedContact` is `undefined`.

```
function getSingleContactFromId(contacts, id) {
  contacts.forEach((contact) => {
    console.log(contact);
    if (contact.id == id) {
      console.log(contact);
      return { contact };
    }
  });
}

const selectedContact = getSingleContactFromId(contacts, id);
      console.log(selectedContact);
```

Comment: try using [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning value from inside the interatee function of the `forEach`. What you can do is to add a variable where you can store the selected contact and return it after exiting the loop.

```
function getSingleContactFromId(contacts, id) {
    let selectedContact;
      contacts.forEach((contact) => {
        console.log(contact);
        if (contact.id == id) {
          console.log(contact);
          selectedContact = { contact };
          return false;
        }
      });
    return selectedContact;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `forEach` returns undefined, returning anything inside it does nothing. You need to use something like `map`, `filter`, or a normal `for` loop and break when you hit a matching id.

Something like this would work:

```
let foundContact = null;
for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
 if (contacts[i].id === id) {
   foundContact = contacts[i];
   break;
 }
}

return foundContact;
```

You can do the same with using filter:

```
return contacts.filter(contact => {
  return contact.id === id;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSingleContactFromId(contacts, id) {
  let c = null;
  contacts.forEach((contact) => {
    if (contact.id === id) {
      c = contact;
      return false;
    }
  });
  return c;
}
```

`return false` is the circuit breaker for `forEach` as `break` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I realized this was a rookie mistake, but I decided to go with this:

```
var contact;
  console.log("get single contact");
  for (var i = 0; i < state.contacts.length; i++) {
    contact = state.contacts[i];
    if (contact.id == id) {
      return contact;
    }
  }
```